# Get name of current network

Tags: delphi, network-programming

I want to find the names of the active and connected networks on Windows with code in Delphi. There can be more than one.

[image: Example of network]

In this screenshot from Windows 10 shows one connected, NETGEAR21.
Would be grateful if someone could answer this.

Comment: There could be more than one. Which one do you want.

Comment: Ok, I clarify in the question. I want a list. Often it is only one network. But you are correct there could be many.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @roland what research have you done?

Comment: I got it working :) I will post the code later here when I got more time

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by first create an interface to Network list manager as described on https://theroadtodelphi.com/2015/10/28/using-the-network-list-manager-nlm-api-from-delphi/. This create the needed file NETWORKLIST_TLB.pas.
Here is the minimal implementation:

```
unit ListTypes;

interface

uses
  ActiveX,
  NETWORKLIST_TLB,
  ComObj;

function SetUpAndGetConnections: String;
function GetConnections: string;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows;

function SetUpAndGetConnections: String;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    Result := GetConnections;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;

function GetConnections: String;
var
  NetworkListManager: INetworkListManager;
  EnumNetworkConnections: IEnumNetworkConnections;
  NetworkConnection : INetworkConnection;
  pceltFetched: ULONG;
begin
   NetworkListManager := CoNetworkListManager.Create;
   EnumNetworkConnections :=  NetworkListManager.GetNetworkConnections();
   Result := '';
   while true do
   begin
     EnumNetworkConnections.Next(1, NetworkConnection, pceltFetched);
     if (pceltFetched>0)  then
        Result := Result + NetworkConnection.GetNetwork.GetName + #13#10
     else
       Break;
   end;
end;

end.
```